# Edit Multiple Records in View with DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am able to edit multiple records from one controller however I have been unable to successfully add a `DropDownList` when editing multiple records in the View.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ReportByNumber() 
{
    ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(from r in db.Departments select r, "Name", "Name");
    return View(reportList.ToList());
}
```

**View** allowing multiple records:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { 

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Department, new { @style = "width:120px" })

}
```

Is there a way to make `Department` a `DropDownList`?

Comment: show definition of `reportList` please

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Teo Van Kot,   var reportList = _db.reportModels.Where(r => r.id >= reportNumLow);

Answer (score 0):

try this:
First in you controller

```
public ActionResult ReportByNumber() 
{
ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(from r in db.Departments select r, "DepartmentID", "Name",selectedDepartment);
return View();
}
```

Second in your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**#Update1**
this is how to bind your **dropdownlist** **value**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReportByNumber([Bind(Include = "DepartmentID")]Departments dept)
    {
    //......
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Feras for your answer.  I will have to test this.  When I first try it  I'm able to show the DropDownList but it doesn't save the values to the Department field.  In the View I'm editing multiple records which is accomplished with the for loop.  I'm not sure if there is a way to add the [i] to the Department field.

Comment: sorry for late, could you add your full code of your view especially your loop

Comment: with this code you don't need to add [i] to the Department field see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

When using `@Html.DropDownList()` in a collection, you need to use an editor template (or reconstruct the `SelectList` in each iteration which is not very efficient). Assuming you model is

```
public class ReportModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
  public string Department { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult ReportByNumber() 
{
  var departments = (from r in db.Departments select r).ToList();
  ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(departments, "Name", "Name");
  return View(reportList.ToList());
}
```

EditorTemplate (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ReportModel.cshtml`)

```
@model ReportModel
....
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, (SelectList)ViewData["DepartmentList"], "-Please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Department)
....
```

Main View

```
@model List<ReportModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { DepartmentList= ViewBag.DepartmentList})
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Notes: The name of the `EditorTemplate` must match the name of your model. You code suggests you just want to bind to the `Name` property of `Department` (not an ID property), in which case it can be just

```
var departments = (from r in db.Departments select r.Name).ToList();
ViewBag.DepartmentList = new SelectList(departments);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Stephen and Feras for putting me on the right track.

I ended up using the code below in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Department, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Department, item.Department ?? "")
```

Comment: Clearly you did not read, or did not understand my answer. This will not work correctly. No matter what you set the values of each `Department` property to, when the page is first loaded, the first option will be selected for each item, not the one you set the value to.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I will study your answer more and test the code.